# NoSuchMethodError: Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance method '[]'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Im trying to get posts(images) for every user.User's id are stored in posts collection and every userid document will have a subcollection will contains all posts document.but im getting this error.

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: []("mediaUrl")
```

this is the code.

```
getPost(){
    return FutureBuilder(
        future:  Firestore.instance.collection('posts').document(user.id
        ).collection('userPosts').getDocuments(),

        // ignore: missing_return
        builder: (context,snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return
              Container(
              height: 200,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                       
                        child: Image.network(snapshot.data["mediaUrl"],)
                    );
                  }
              ),
          ],
              ),
            );


          }
          if (!snapshot.data ) {
            return Text('No posts');
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        }
    );
  }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your media url is inside a document then try this :

```
Image.network(snapshot.data.documents[index]["mediaUrl"],)
```

Full code with another approach :

```
getPost(){
    return FutureBuilder(
        future:  Firestore.instance.collection('posts').document(user.id
        ).collection('userPosts').getDocuments(),

        // ignore: missing_return
        builder: (context,snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return
              Container(
              height: 200,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                       DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                        return Image.network(docSnapshot["mediaUrl"],)
                    );
                  }
              ),
          ],
              ),
            );


          }
          if (!snapshot.data ) {
            return Text('No posts');
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        }
    );
  }
```